# how to convert NSString to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, ios

i tried to convert this NSString date to NSDate

```
NSString *update_time= @"2012-03-09 14:54:30.0";

// convert to date
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'.0'"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Australia/Melbourne"]];
NSDate *dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:update_time ];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", dte);
```

but i'm getting **Date: (null)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"GMT+4" is not a valid timzone name. Use `timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:` instead:

```
//...
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:4 * (60 * 60)];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:timeZone];
//...
```

If you want to use `timeZoneWithName:`, you can get a list of valid timezone names using `[NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]`. Those all have the form "Europe/Berlin" etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *update_time= @"2012-03-09 14:54:30.0";
```

Missing the pointer

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a pointer.

```
  NSString * update_time= @"2012-03-09 14:54:30.0";

// convert to date
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'.0'"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT+4"]];
NSDate *dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:update_time ];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", dte);
```